# Is the reasonableness of a belief or moral claim relative?

Tags: ethics, rationality, belief, liberalism

Is the reasonableness of a belief or moral claim relative? I found some articles on the ethical word "reasonable", but lack access. Apparently it is key to "liberal" political projects like Rawls', but - aside form its legal meaning - I also associate it with divine command theory in the 21st century.

Prima facie, we can be wrong about what is reasonable, so it may be objective. But the word may seem to be associated closely enough with human judgment that what is "reasonable" varies at least according to progress (say, it *was* reasonable to believe in God).

Comment: Rawls drew a distinction between the rational and the reasonable (IIRC this distinction is not emphasized or even formulated in *A Theory of Justice*, but I don't recall where it shows up so strongly otherwise). Offhand, private/strongly individual grounded inference is the rational and what's reasonable is more about [public reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rawls/#PubRea).

Comment: i have a pre-theoretical sense of the word 'reasonable': does anyone say we should always at least try to be reasonable, as part of our ethical duties, and supposing there is some sort of reasonable component to many of them, then how does that link to divine command theory @KristianBerry